# Can an automated apps script email notification link back to specific sheet?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

much to my surprise I've successfully made an apps scripts that sends me email notifications when a specific cell is changed to 'Submitted,' but I have no idea how to make this identify the sheet it came from - have linked a copy of the sheet below, there are going to be around 20 of these, each with 6 submission sheets, and I need to do a thing as soon as the sheet has been marked submitted, i.e. same day. I'd rather not hard code in separate messages for each sheet, can I do something around getting the URL and sheet with the get active sheet coding and insert it into the email message? I'm also aware currently I've hard coded in the sheet names and therefore need 6 different triggers, I'm working on that - tried loads of different coding pages and this is the only one that worked!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b0LOr9vhmFu4WtYy_RbS-1cvXncNOI_x3YT0f30fZgY/edit#gid=1979912158

Cheers,
Meg

```
    function emailSubmit() {
MailApp.sendEmail("Testemail", "Test", "Test message");
}
function onEdit(e) {
  const specificSheet = "Sub1"
  const specificCell = "C11"

  let sheetCheck = (e.range.getSheet().getName() == specificSheet)
  let cellCheck = (e.range.getA1Notation() == specificCell)
  if (!(sheetCheck && cellCheck) || e.value !== "Submitted") {
    return;
  }
  else {
    emailSubmit()
  }
}
function onEdit2(e) {
  const specificSheet = "Sub2"
  const specificCell = "C11"

  let sheetCheck = (e.range.getSheet().getName() == specificSheet)
  let cellCheck = (e.range.getA1Notation() == specificCell)

  if (!(sheetCheck && cellCheck)) {
    return
  }
  else {
    emailSubmit()
  }
}
```

Comment: The sheet is e.range.getSheet() and there is a one to one mapping between the sheet and the form so you can create an object such that object['sheetname

Comment: What is your exact question? You do not understand why your code works?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear! At the moment I don't know how to make the email message say 'this specific spreadsheet and tab have been submitted' in order to identify which one of the 20 spreadsheets the message has come from, and that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

### To obtain the spreadsheet object bound to the fired onEdit trigger, use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) `source`

[image]

**Sample:**

```js
function emailSubmit(spreadsheet, sheet) {
  console.log("spreadsheet: " + spreadsheet);
  console.log("sheet: " + sheet);
  MailApp.sendEmail("Testemail", "Test", "Spreadsheet " + spreadsheet + " and tab " + sheet + "have been submitted");
}
function onEdit(e) {
  const allowedSheets = ["Sub1","Sub2"];
  const specificCell = "C11";
  const spreadsheetName = e.source.getName();
  const sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  
  let sheetCheck = (allowedSheets.indexOf(sheetName) != -1);
  let cellCheck = (e.range.getA1Notation() == specificCell);
  if (!(sheetCheck && cellCheck) || e.value !== "Submitted") {
    return;
  }
  else {
    emailSubmit(spreadsheetName, sheetName);
  }
}
```

References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getname)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I'm getting through both spreadsheet and sheet as undefined, and I think it's because I haven't linked up getting the names with the email? I could be wrong... Thanks for the references as well, I think I might give up this project as too advanced and do the reading first!

Comment: Do you get the undefined when you run the function `emailSubmit` manually from the script editor? As per the implementation above, this function should be called automatically by `onEdit(e)` when the `else` condition if fulfilled. Make sure you don't have more than one function called `onEdit` within your code and implement additional logs into your functions for troubleshooting.